# Subtraction with Date Time Offset Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sometime you experience a mind freeze and think how do you do that . I am executing the SQL below AND need the answer IN a specific format, but cant work it out.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ( mm, '2017-03-07 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00' , '2017-03-07 12:45:00.0000000 +00:00' )
```

Need the answer IN this format ? 01:15:00.0000000 ( hh:mm:ss.0000000)

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "mi" for minutes, you've got months.  Given that, this gets you closer:  `SELECT DATEADD(mi, ABS(DATEDIFF ( MINUTE, '2017-03-07 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00' , '2017-03-07 12:45:00.0000000 +00:00' )), 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option:

**Example**

```
Declare @D1 varchar(50) = '2017-03-07 12:45:00.0000000 +00:00'
Declare @D2 varchar(50) = '2017-03-07 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00'

SELECT format(dateadd(Second,datediff(SECOND,convert(datetime2,@D1),convert(datetime2,@D2)),0),'HH:mm:ss.0000000')
```

**Returns**

```
01:15:00.0000000
```

Comment: Correct answer . Thank you to other 2 responders but this is the only one that gives exactly what is needed.

Comment: @JamesKhan Happy it helped

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your time spans could surpass 24 hours and you haven't requested # of days, only hours, you can use this.

```
declare @StartDate varchar(64) = '2017-03-05 12:45:00.0000000 +00:00' 
declare @EndDate varchar(64) = '2017-03-07 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00'

declare @seconds int = DATEDIFF(second,@StartDate,@EndDate)


SELECT 
    RIGHT('00'+CAST(@seconds/3600 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00'+CAST(@seconds/60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('00''00'+CAST(@seconds % 60 AS VARCHAR) , 2) +
    CAST(0000000 AS VARCHAR(7)) AS [HH:MM:SS:MS]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CONVERT

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, COLUMN1 - COLUMN2)
FROM TABLE
```